# Xamarin forms: ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid:

Tags: image, xamarin.forms

Getting below error message when trying to show an image on UI.

Exception details:

```
[0:] ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid: Uri: "imageurl"
[0:] Image Loading: Error getting stream for "imageurl": System.ObjectDisposedException: Can not access a closed Stream.
  at System.IO.StreamHelpers.ValidateCopyToArgs (System.IO.Stream source, System.IO.Stream destination, System.Int32 bufferSize) [0x0003a] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.CopyToAsync (System.IO.Stream destination, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.UriImageSource.GetStreamAsyncUnchecked (System.String key, System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00310] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\UriImageSource.cs:185 
  at Xamarin.Forms.UriImageSource.GetStreamFromCacheAsync (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00140] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\UriImageSource.cs:209 
  at Xamarin.Forms.UriImageSource.GetStreamAsync (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000f0] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\UriImageSource.cs:139 
  at Xamarin.Forms.UriImageSource.GetStreamAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken userToken) [0x00056] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\UriImageSource.cs:78 
Debugger Connection Lost: Debugger lost connection to the running application. Likely this means the application terminated unexpectedly.
```

**Version Details**

```
Xamarin forms Version: 4.2.0.848062
Target Framework: Android 9.0 Pie
Target Android Version: Android 9.0(API Level 28 - Pie)
```

I am using below code for showing image on UI:

**image.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(ImageUrl));**

The issue is only with the android project. Go through some similar issue threads, but none of them helps me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load image from remote url is not very friendly on Android . So I suggest that you ca use the plugin [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) . **FFImageLoading** for Forms provides CachedImage - a direct Image class replacement. It’s used just the same but it has some additional properties.

Firstly,Add the following NuGet packages to **every project(iOS and Android)** in your solution.

```
Xamarin.FFImageLoading

Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms,

Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Transformations (if you’ll use transformations like CircleTransformation)

Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg (for SVG support)

Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms (for SVG support)

SkiaSharp (for SVG support)
```

Then init the renderer in sepecfic platforms before you init the forms.

in iOS -> AppDelegate.cs

```
FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init();
```

in Android ->MainActivity.cs

```
FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init(enableFastRenderer: true);
```

#### in xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="FFImageLoading.Forms.Sample.Pages.XamlSimpleExamplePage"
    xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
    Title="Basic XAML Example">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
            Source = "{Binding xxx}">
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</PFContentPage>
```

And here is a similar case that you can check [ImageCell not displaying image only on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213955/imagecell-not-displaying-image-only-on-android) .

Answer (score 0):

As long as this appears in android only, another quick solution would be to use an external image handler, install `glidex.forms` nuget (https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/glidex) into your android project,

and enable it im MainActivity.cs

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

//This forces the custom renderers to be used - ad after Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init
Android.Glide.Forms.Init (this);

LoadApplication (new App ());
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this error in my logs but my app was crashing for some other reason which was occurring just prior to trying to display the image. In my case it was crashing while attempting to send a notification. After commenting out the notification code then the image displayed just fine.

An additional note about the Glidex solution presented by Nick Kovalsky, when installing Glidex from Nuget make sure to only install the package on the Android project, otherwise a bunch of errors are presented which can result in other issues.

In the end the Glidex did not really help me and the FFImageLoading just didn't work out either.